# can i access mongoDB console in nodeJs-mongoDb driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Nodejs mongoDb driver code to access and create database

```
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var db = new mongo.Db("myapp", new mongo.Server("localhost", 27017));
var people = db.collection("people");
```

and to query

```
people.find()
```

Is there any way i can access mongoDb console in nodeJs mongoDb driver so i can test my queries there

Comment: why need to take it in driver? when the console can be directly accessed

Answer (score 1):

Any command you run in the console can be run through the driver using the .command function on the Db object. However I suggest you use the console of for management as it's a bit easier than duplicating the effort using the driver.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [mongo-sync](https://npmjs.org/package/mongo-sync) or [Mongolian DeadBeef](https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian/) which are advertised as nodejs drivers which more closely pattern the mongo command line interface.  I would use them with caution though, since they are not core mongo supported drivers.